# Flask NoneType error appears randomly even tho type is correct, and sometimes, it works randomly

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

#Here is my class:

```
class CryptoClass:

  def __init__(self, cfrom, cto):
      self.cfrom = cfrom
      self.cto   = cto
    
  def priceConverter(self):
      dic = cryptocompare.get_price([self.cfrom],[self.cto])
      return [self.cfrom,self.cto,dic[self.cfrom][self.cto]]
```

#Here is the function:

```
def converter():
    
    A = str(request.form.get("FROM"))
    B = str(request.form.get("TO"))
    
    if A!="" and B!="":
        price1 = CryptoClass(A,B)
        a = price1.priceConverter()
      
        
        return render_template("converter.html", fromResult =  a[0],toResult = a[2],toResultName = a[1])
```

#Finally, here is the Error I'm getting:

```
return [self.cfrom,self.cto,dic[self.cfrom][self.cto]]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

What I find weird with my problem is the fact that sometimes, it works, and sometimes it doesn't, but I can't find the logic behind it, any help would be appreciated :)

P.S: If I replace A and B by A = "BTC" and B = "ETH", it works like a charm, I made sure the request is actually working and tried printing A and B using values from the form, but when I put all the code together, I can't even access the form page since I'd have this error popping.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your issue is caused by two things:

1. Invalid values (`FROM` and `TO`);
2. The `cryptocompare.get_price` response.

Let's start with `1`. You have three possible scenarios in your request handling, both values were provided and are **valid cryptocurency** (let say `FROM=ETH` and `TO=BTC`), **only one value** was provided (`FROM=ETH` or `TO=BTC`) and when some of the values provided (or both) is not a **valid cryptocurrency**(`FROM=XYZ` and `TO=AAAAAAAA`).

Let's deal with the last two, since the first one is already covered in your source code.

**Values not provided**: be sure to suggest a default value when calling `request.form.get()` or be aware that, in case the requested value does not exist, this function **will** return None (not an empty string). Also, It would be good to improve your code like this:

```
A = request.form.get("FROM", "")
B = request.form.get("TO", "")
```

**Invalid Cryptocurrencies**: On this point I'm making some assumptions (based on Web API calls to [min-api.cryptocompare.com](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=AAA) and the [source code](https://github.com/lagerfeuer/cryptocompare/blob/5482df6ef3b1f710ef65936dd42cb6f0b84df1f8/cryptocompare/cryptocompare.py#L47). When you call `cryptocompare.get_price` with invalid arguments, let's say `cryptocompare.get_price(['BTC'], ['AAAAAAAAA'])`, it return a None object.

Having that in mind, the value of `dic` will be `None`, and when you try to run this `dic[self.cfrom][self.cto]` you will be trying to subscript a `None` object. Hence, the error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

It's recommended to check the `dic` object before the return statement:

```
dic = cryptocompare.get_price([self.cfrom],[self.cto])
if dic:
    return [self.cfrom,self.cto,dic[self.cfrom][self.cto]]
return [self.cfrom,self.cto,None]
```

Note that if the `dic` is `None` the last part of the list in the return statement is `None` too, and need to be treated accordingly in the portion of your code that receive this response.

Good luck!